# Will a Python dict literal be evaluated in the order it is written?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say that I've got a situation like this in Python:

```
_avg = {'total':0.0, 'count':0}    # HACK: side-effects stored here

def procedure(n):
  _avg['count'] += 1
  _avg['total'] += n
  return n

def get_average():
  return _avg['total'] / _avg['count']

my_dict = {
  'key0': procedure(0),
  'key2': procedure(2),
  'key1': get_average()
}
assert(my_dict['key1'] == 1.0)
```

I know that the order of `my_dict.keys()` is undefined, but what I'm wondering is whether the *initialization* via a literal like this is guaranteed to happen in a particular order. Will the value of `my_dict['key1']` always be `1.0` as asserted?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Dictionary evaluation order **should** be the same as written, but there is a [outstanding bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue11205) where *values* are evaluated before the *keys*. (The bug was finally fixed in Python 3.5).

Quoting from the [reference documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order):

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right.

and from the bug report:

> Running the following code shows `"2 1 4 3"`, but in reference manual
>   http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists the
>   evaluation order described as `{expr1: expr2, expr3: expr4}`
>
> ```
> def f(i):
>     print i
>     return i
>
> {f(1):f(2), f(3):f(4)}
> ```

and Guido stated:

> I am sticking with my opinion from before: the code should be fixed.  It doesn't look like assignment to me.

This bug is fixed in Python 3.5, so on Python 3.4 and earlier the values are still evaluated before the keys:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> def f(i):
...     print(i)
...     return i
... 
>>> {f(1):f(2), f(3):f(4)}
2
1
4
3
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

Since your code doesn't require the keys to be evaluated first, your code is guaranteed to work correctly; key-value pairs are still evaluated in order even if the keys are evaluated after each corresponding value.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Python docs regarding evaluation order](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order), this should have well-defined behavior:

> In the following lines, expressions will be evaluated in the arithmetic order of their suffixes:
>
> ```
> …
> {expr1: expr2, expr3: expr4}
> …
> ```

So, regardless of what order the items in a `dict` end up being *iterated*, the values (and keys!) of a literal dictionary expression will always be *evaluated* in the same order as they appear in my Python source code.

Comment: Good call. Although if this really matters to your code, you should probably unit test this, particularly for portability reasons.

Comment: Except for http://bugs.python.org/issue11205, which shows that there is a bug in the Python implementation with that rule.

Answer (score 2):

The current behaviour on Python 3.4.2 can be very clearly seen in the disassembled bytecode: the values are evaluated before keys, not left-to-right.

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: {f('1'): f('2'), f('3'): f('4')})
  1           0 BUILD_MAP                2
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('2')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f)
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 ('1')
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             21 STORE_MAP
             22 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f)
             25 LOAD_CONST               3 ('4')
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             31 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f)
             34 LOAD_CONST               4 ('3')
             37 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             40 STORE_MAP
             41 RETURN_VALUE
```

However this also shows the reason why this is also not so straightforward to fix: the values and keys are expected by [`STORE_MAP`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_MAP) in this order; changing the order would either require adding a [`ROT_TWO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_TWO) opcode after each pair, or 
`STORE_MAP_EX` opcode which would expect the pairs to be reversed; the first one would be a performance drop, whereas the second would mean yet another opcode to handle in every piece of code that deals with bytecode.