# Are Python dictionaries literals evaluated in order?

Tags: python, dictionary

When I run this

```
import itertools

bar = itertools.count(1).next

print {'a': bar(), 'b': bar(), 'c': bar()}
```

on CPython, I get `{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}`. Is this consistent across implementations and/or documented anywhere? Will `a`, `b` and `c` ever be assigned values out of order?

Comment: <s>I don't think so.  Considering that dictionary keys are not guaranteed to be in any order in the first place, I don't think you can make any guarantee as to what other the interpreter builds a dict literal.  It's an interesting question though.</s> Nope, apparently from some of the answers below the Python docs do make a prescription on this, though that's good.

Comment: I'm not sure it will always work for you. Maybe if you initialize it inline like in your example it works. I'm pretty sure that if you create a new dict and assign the values in the same order, it won't  be kept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) (emphasize mine):

> If a comma-separated sequence of key/datum pairs is given, **they are evaluated from left to right to define the entries of the dictionary**: each key object is used as a key into the dictionary to store the corresponding datum....

So, pairs will always be **evaluated** in order. But don't get confused with the order of the elements.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156687/will-a-python-dict-literal-be-evaluated-in-the-order-it-is-written) (I do not have enough reputation to add this as a comment).

In sum, "Dictionary evaluation order should be the same as written, but there is a outstanding bug where values are evaluated before the keys.'

Comment: That's fine. My question is whether the **pairs** are evaluated in order.

Comment: Here, have an upvote so you can leave a comment next time.

Comment: And another from me.

Comment: Commenting level unlocked - I see bright days ahead. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. A better test would be to use integers, as these hash to their own values, and to use them out of order in the literal, so that you can see which order they were evaluated in. When you do that, you see:

```
>>> print {1: bar(), 3: bar(), 2: bar()}
{1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2}
```

which implies that they are evaluated in order from left to right, even though they are not stored in the dictionary in that order.

Comment: That still has nothing to do with the order in which the dictionary literal is evaluated by the interpreter.

Comment: Yes it does: the point of the bar() function is that it returns the incrementing counter, which shows the order it was called. Here we see that 1 was called first, then 3, then 2, so the literal was evaluated left to right.