# Order of operations in a dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I came across the following interesting construct:

assuming you have a list of lists as follows:

```
my_list = [['captain1', 'foo1', 'bar1', 'foobar1'], ['captain2', 'foo2', 'bar2', 'foobar2'], ...]
```

and you want to create a dict out of them with the `0`-index elements being the keys. A handy way to do it would be this:

```
my_dict = {x.pop(0): x for x in my_list}
# {'captain1': ['foo1', 'bar1', 'foobar1'], ...}
```

As it seems, the `pop` precedes the assignment of list `x` as the value and that is why `'captain'` does not appear in the values (it is already popped)

Now let's take this a step further and try to get a structure like:

```
# {'captain1': {'column1': 'foo1', 'column2': 'bar1', 'column3': 'foobar1'}, ...}
```

For this task I wrote the following:

```
my_headers = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']
my_dict = {x.pop(0): {k: v for k, v in zip(my_headers, x)} for x in my_list}
```

but this returns:

```
# {'captain1': {'col3': 'bar1', 'col1': 'captain1', 'col2': 'foo1'}, 'captain2': {'col3': 'bar2', 'col1': 'captain2', 'col2': 'foo2'}}
```

so the `pop` in this case happens after the inner dictionary is constructed (or at least after the `zip`).

How can that be? How does this work?

The question is not about how to do it but rather why this behavior is seen.

I am using Python version **3.5.1.**

Comment: I think that's because the values gets evaluate first.

Comment: @Kasramvd Do you have anything supporting that claim?

Comment: @skyking As far as I know that's how comprehensions works. It'll evaluates the nested comprehension first, in such cases.

Comment: @skyking It seems that it's True even for non-comprehension values. Try `{x.pop(0): x.pop(0) for x in [[1, 2]]}`. But note that it's doesn't perform like this when the list you are popping from is an internal object like a predefined list.

Comment: FWIW, `.pop(0)` should generally be avoided when possible, because it's slow: all of the remaining list items have to be moved down. Sure, that happens at C speed, but it's still a performance hit.

Comment: @Kasramvd Yes, or for the OP's example: `my_dict = {x.pop(0): dict(zip(my_headers, x)) for x in my_list}` results in same output

Comment: Also, feeding raw `zip` output to a dict comp is a little verbose, passing the `zip` directly to the `dict` constructor is more compact. `my_dict = {x[0]: dict(zip(my_headers, x[1:])) for x in my_list}`

Comment: @PM2Ring I noticed from Chris' comment. It is much better indeed.

Comment: Not exactly related, since the questions stands in spite of this, but you **should avoid operations that have side-effects like `.pop` or `.append` in comprehension constructs. That is bad form.

Comment: @Kasramvd Your knowledge doesn't seem to be supported by any specifications on how comprehensions work. There is simply seem to be no guarantee that the value is evaluated before the key.

Comment: Please, avoid putting material that does not belong to the question on a question. The question should only contain the problem and the information required to reproduce it, anything related to solving the problem either belongs to answers or comments. Don't put a "summary" of the answers on the question: that belongs to the answer (if the answer's author deem it appropriate).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Note**: As of Python 3.8 and [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), this was changed and the keys are evaluated first.

---

***tl;dr Until Python 3.7***: Even though Python *does* evaluate values first (the right-side of the expression) *this does appear to be a bug* in (C)Python according to [the reference manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) and [the grammar](https://github.com/DimitrisJim/cpython/blob/79ab8be05fb4ffb5c258d2ca49be5fc2d4880431/Grammar/Grammar#L118) and the [PEP on dict comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#semantics).

Though this was previously [fixed for dictionary displays](http://bugs.python.org/issue11205) where values were again evaluated before the keys, *the patch wasn't amended* to include dict-comprehensions. [This requirement was also mentioned by one of the core-devs in a mailing list thread discussing this same subject](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-November/122584.html).

According to the reference manual, Python evaluates *expressions from left to right* and *assignments from right to left*; a dict-comprehension is really an expression containing expressions, *not an assignment*<sup>*</sup>:

```
{expr1: expr2 for ...}
```

where, according to the corresponding [rule of the `grammar`](https://github.com/DimitrisJim/cpython/blob/79ab8be05fb4ffb5c258d2ca49be5fc2d4880431/Grammar/Grammar#L118) one would expect `expr1: expr2` to be evaluated similarly to what it does in displays. So, both expressions should follow the defined order, `expr1` should be evaluated before `expr2` (and, if `expr2` contains expressions of its own, they too should be evaluated from left to right.)

The PEP on dict-comps additionally states that the following should be semantically equivalent:

> The semantics of dict comprehensions can actually be demonstrated in
>   stock Python 2.2, by passing a list comprehension to the built-in
>   dictionary constructor:
>
> `>>> dict([(i, chr(65+i)) for i in range(4)])`
>
> is semantically equivalent to:
>
> `>>> {i : chr(65+i) for i in range(4)}`

were the tuple `(i, chr(65+i))` is evaluated left to right as expected.

Changing this to behave according to the rules for expressions would create an inconsistency in the creation of `dict`s, of course. Dictionary comprehensions and a for loop with assignments result in a  different evaluation order but, that's fine since it is just following the rules.

Though this isn't a major issue it should be fixed (either the rule of evaluation, or the docs) to disambiguate the situation.

<sup>*</sup>*Internally*, this does result in an assignment to a dictionary object but, this shouldn't break the behavior expressions should have. Users have expectations about how expressions should behave as stated in the reference manual.

---

As the other answerers pointed out, since you perform a mutating action in one of the expressions, you toss out any information on what gets evaluated first; using `print` calls, as Duncan did, sheds light on what is done.

A function to help in showing the discrepancy:

```
def printer(val):
    print(val, end=' ')
    return val
```

(Fixed) dictionary display:

```
>>> d = {printer(0): printer(1), printer(2): printer(3)}
0 1 2 3
```

(Odd) dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> t = (0, 1), (2, 3)
>>> d = {printer(i):printer(j) for i,j in t}
1 0 3 2
```

and yes, this applies specifically for `C`Python. I am not aware of how other implementations evaluate this specific case (though they should all conform to the Python Reference Manual.)

Digging through the source is always nice (and you also find hidden comments describing the behavior too), so let's peek in `compiler_sync_comprehension_generator` of the file [`compile.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3cdbd68ce8230cff1afb67472b96fbfa7f047e32/Python/compile.c#L3752):

```
case COMP_DICTCOMP:
    /* With 'd[k] = v', v is evaluated before k, so we do
       the same. */
    VISIT(c, expr, val);
    VISIT(c, expr, elt);
    ADDOP_I(c, MAP_ADD, gen_index + 1);
    break;
```

this might seem like a good enough reason and, if it is judged as such, should be classified as a documentation bug, instead.

On a quick test I did, switching these statements around (`VISIT(c, expr, elt);` getting visited first) while also switching the corresponding [order in `MAP_ADD`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e32ec9334b35f897ace8a05128838f92c5e0b2fb/Python/ceval.c#L2754) (which is used for dict-comps):

```
TARGET(MAP_ADD) {
    PyObject *value = TOP();   # was key 
    PyObject *key = SECOND();  # was value
    PyObject *map;
    int err;
```

results in the evaluation one would expect based on the docs, with the key evaluated before the value. (Not for their asynchronous versions, that's another switch required.)

---

<strike>I'll drop a comment on the issue and update when and if someone gets back to me.</strike>

Created [Issue 29652 -- Fix evaluation order of keys/values in dict comprehensions](http://bugs.python.org/issue29652) on the tracker. Will update the question when progress is made on it.

Comment: the *odd dict-comp* is definitely odd.. It is simply weird that Python operates almost randomly when it comes to the order of operations in dict-comprehensions. At the end the result is the same if the comprehension does not use methods that alter their objects but `pop` does.. For me that is the only reason `pop` is *bad* practice. I find the construct otherwise fairly useful..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis indeed it is. Though a bug, I wouldn't be surprised if the effort required to fix it is greater than the benefit of actually fixing it (it is a real corner-case that, unless you're up to wacky things, shouldn't be an issue).  You could drop a comment on the issue that fixed this for dict displays and see what the devs think.

Comment: *a dict-comprehension is really an expression containing expressions, not an assignment*. I disagree. Dictionary comprehension is an expression but python will translate it to a simple assignment and hence it will follows the assignment rule!

Comment: I am afraid i wouldn't know how to do that. If you think it is worth it feel free to do it yourself. Post the link if you do so that I can follow it up. Thanks!

Comment: @Kasramvd though I agree that it *does* translate to an assignment internally, I disagree that it shouldn't be changed (i.e it is correct). On the python level, It presents itself as an expression  and *should* behave that way, regardless of how it was decided this should be implemented. (Implementation detail shouldn't break the reference).

Comment: So this is not a code bug, it's in fact a documentation bug.

Comment: How does that reference manual part support the claim that this is a bug? It doesn't say anything about dict comprehensions there.

Comment: @StefanPochmann according to the grammar, `dict`-comp is an extension of the dict-display, [the initial `test : test` expression is the same](https://github.com/DimitrisJim/cpython/blob/79ab8be05fb4ffb5c258d2ca49be5fc2d4880431/Grammar/Grammar#L118), i.e same rules should be expected to apply.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Hmm, [*here*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) (that's on the same page) they go separate ways, sharing only the surrounding braces.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yes, the docs explaining the grammar don't use the same exact notation as the grammar proper, not sure why (maybe easier to explain). Either way, I based the assertion that they are similar on the source for the grammar (and, really, them not being the same would *also* be a point of confusion).

Comment: The original [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) for dict comprehensions also supports evaluating keys before values, by saying that a dict comprehension is semantically equivalent to passing `dict` a list comprehension that creates key-value tuples.

Comment: I was expecting to find something somewhere official declaring that a dict comprehension was equivalent to a loop involving `d[k] = v`, which would support evaluating values first, but I didn't find anything. (It bugs the crap out of me that `d[k] = v` evaluates `v` before `d` and `k` at all, but that's not a battle I'm likely to win.)

Comment: Wouldn't the implementation of comps be considered an implementation detail and thus not documented @user2357112? The little comment in the source was the best I found on the subject.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard: The implementation is undocumented, but declaring the semantics equivalent to some example implementation would only be documenting the semantics, not the real implementation.

Answer (score 14):

> As it seems, the pop precedes the assignment of list x as the value 
>      and that is why 'captain' does not appear in the values (it is already
>      popped)

No, the order in which it happens is irrelevant. You are mutating the list so you will see the modified list after the pop wherever you use it. Note that in general you probably don't want to do this as you will destroy the original list. Even if that doesn't matter this time its a trap for the unwary in the future.

In both cases the value side is calculated first and then the corresponding key. It's just that in your first case it doesn't matter whereas it does in the second.

You can see this quite easily:

```
>>> def foo(a): print("foo", a)
... 
>>> def bar(a): print("bar", a)
... 
>>> { foo(a):bar(a) for a in (1, 2, 3) }
('bar', 1)
('foo', 1)
('bar', 2)
('foo', 2)
('bar', 3)
('foo', 3)
{None: None}
>>>
```

Note that you should not write code that depends on the values being evaluated first: the behaviour may change in future versions (it was said in some places to have changed in Python 3.5 and later although in fact that appears not to be the case).

A simpler way to do this, which avoids mutating the original data structure:

```
my_dict = {x[0]: x[1:] for x in my_list}
```

Or your second example:

```
my_headers = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']
my_dict = {x[0]: {k: v for k, v in zip(my_headers, x[1:])} for x in my_list}
```

To answer the comments: the zip uses the original `x` because it is evaluated before the `pop`, but it uses the content of the list to construct a new list so any later changes to the list aren't seen in the result. The first comprehension also uses the original `x` as the value, but it then mutates the list so the value still sees the original list and hence the mutation.

Comment: but then why does the `zip(header, x)` makes use of the unmodified `x`?

Comment: because in both cases the value part of the dictionary comprehension executes before the key side.

Comment: the only problem I have with the slicing approach is that the elements that is actually the *captain* is not the first one so i have to merge two slices. I did not dv btw.

Comment: I've extended my answer to show how you can tell the order of evaluation with some prints. No problem on the dv, It would be nice if whoever did it said why they don't like the answer but I don't mind the odd downvote.

Comment: That dict comprehension with the prints is a smart way to show order. Thanks

Comment: "*No, the order in which it happens is irrelevant. You are mutating the list so you will see the modified list after the pop wherever you use it*". If it is so why does `zip` use the original `x`?

Comment: I don't see how this fully answers the original question; and keys should be evaluated first no? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156687/will-a-python-dict-literal-be-evaluated-in-the-order-it-is-written

Comment: @Chris_Rands, yes I've added in a warning not to depend on the order of evaluation because it does in fact depend on the Python version.

Comment: +1 for the slicing methods shown at the end. Clear and concise. imho much better than relying on the evaluation order of `x` and `x.pop(0)`.  It's a little more to write, but it's clear and robust.

Answer (score 7):

As I said in comment that's because in a dictionary comprehension python evaluates the value first. And as a more pythonic approach you can use unpacking variables for this task, instead of popping from list in each iteration:

```
In [32]: my_list = [['captain1', 'foo1', 'bar1', 'foobar1'], ['captain2', 'foo2', 'bar2', 'foobar2']]

In [33]: {frist: {"column{}".format(i): k for i, k in enumerate(last, 1)} for frist, *last in my_list}
Out[33]: 
{'captain2': {'column3': 'foobar2', 'column1': 'foo2', 'column2': 'bar2'},
 'captain1': {'column3': 'foobar1', 'column1': 'foo1', 'column2': 'bar1'}}
```

Regarding the strange behavior of python in evaluating the keys and values in a dictionary comprehension, after some experiments I realized that this behavior is somehow reasonable rather than being a bug.

I'll brake down my impression in following parts:

1. In an assignment expression, python evaluates the right side first.
   from doc:

   > Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.
2. Dictionary comprehension is an expression and will be evaluated left to right but since there is an assignment under the hood, after translating it by python.
   the value which is the right had side will be evaluated first.

   for example the following comprehension:

   `{b.pop(0): b.pop(0) for _ in range(1)}`
   is equivalent with following snippet:

---

```
def dict_comprehension():
    the_dict = {}
    for _ in range(1):
        the_dict[b.pop(0)] = b.pop(0)
    return the_dict
```

Here are some examples:

```
In [12]: b = [4, 0]

# simple rule : Python evaluates expressions from left to right.
In [13]: [[b.pop(0), b.pop(0)] for _ in range(1)]
Out[13]: [[4, 0]]

In [14]: b = [4, 0]
# while evaluating an assignment (aforementioned rule 1), the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.
In [15]: {b.pop(0): b.pop(0) for _ in range(1)}
Out[15]: {0: 4}

In [16]: b = [4, 0]
# This is not a dictionary comprehension and will be evaluated left to right.
In [17]: {b.pop(0): {b.pop(0) for _ in range(1)}}
Out[17]: {4: {0}}

In [18]: b = [4, 0]
# This is not a dictionary comprehension and will be evaluated left to right.
In [19]: {b.pop(0): b.pop(0) == 0}
Out[19]: {4: True}

In [20]: b = [4, 0]
# dictionary comprehension.
In [21]: {b.pop(0): {b.pop(0) for _ in range(1)} for _ in range(1)}
Out[21]: {0: {4}}
```

---

Regarding the disparity between the the fact (Or it's better to say abstraction) that dictionary comprehensions are expression and should be evaluated left to right (based on python documentation)
with the observed behaviors I think it's actually a problem and immaturity of the python documentation and not a bug in python code. Because it's not reasonable at all to change the functionality because of the having a consistent documentation without any exception.

Comment: Which definition of `my_list` are you using?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis It was a modified list ;) checkout the update.

Comment: This is curious, +1, but is this a specified language feature? It's hard to know how widely this applies is from a single example. I was under the impression keys should be evaluated first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156687/will-a-python-dict-literal-be-evaluated-in-the-order-it-is-written

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes python evaluates the expressions form left to right but it seems that this is an exception.

Comment: It almost seems like a bug to me. Also I'm still not clear on the OP's example, because `my_list` is 'external' in both their examples

Comment: @Chris_Rands As I said being external or internal is important for the lists that you are pop from not you're looping over. But Yes it seems like a bog but don't be so sure. I'm looking for a reason in source code but unfortunately I couldn't find anything yet.

Answer (score 4):

Actually your observation doesn't require special ordering of the operation. The reason is that `x.pop(0)` modifies the object `x`. So whether you evaluate the value (`x`) before or after the key (`x.pop(0)`) doesn't matter in this case.

Anyway I don't think the python language specification prescribes a certain order of operations, which means that you should not rely on the order being any particular.

Actually the standard implementation **happens** to evaluate the value before it evaluates the key, but there's nowhere in the standard where this is stated. The only guarantee is that the key-value pairs are evaluating in iteration order and they are inserted in that order.

Comment: but then why does the `zip(header, x)` makes use of the unmodified `x`?

Comment: It was not me mate.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis That's OK, stackoverflow is full of people that votes down answers without explanation...