# Why raw_input is taking value first?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

```
stu_dict = [{raw_input():int(raw_input())} for i in xrange(1)] 
print stu_dict
```

For the above code, the input should be as follows:
`4` and `r`  and it prints as `[{'r': 4}]`, that means it's taking `4` as value and `r` as key here!

But for the below code, it is reverse, first input will be assigned to key, and second to value

```
a = [[raw_input(), float(raw_input())] for i in xrange(int(raw_input()))] 
print a
```

Why is it so?

Comment: values are evaluated before keys in a `dict`, `list`s are evaluated left to right

Comment: @Chris_Rands nope. Not in Python >= 3.5. By the spec, keys *should be evaluated before values*, but there was an outstanding bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue11205

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga they are using 2.7

Comment: @Chris_Rands right, and it is a *bug* in 2.7. According to the spec, it should be left-to-right.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I originally was getting mixed up between `dict` literals and the comprehension syntax, where values are evaluated before keys, even in Python 3, e.g. `{input(): input() for i in range(1)}`

Comment: @Chris_Rands the dict-comprehension evaluation order is *another* currently unfixed bug. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201932/order-of-operations-in-a-dictionary-comprehension)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I didn't think it was a bug, i though it was to be consistent with `d = {}; d[input()] = input()` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands It would count as a bug. One could also assume the value should not evaluated should in case the key is not hashable for example.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Good point but Raymond Hettinger seems to think it's not a bug for `dict` comps and that it won't therefore be 'fixed' https://bugs.python.org/issue29652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears in Python 2, for each key/datum pair, the datum is evaluated first, and then the sequence of pairs, if any, are evaluated from left to right.

However, this is not so in Python>=3.5 where the bug was fixed and keys are evaluated first.

You can force the intended behavior by building the dict from a sequence of 2-tuples:

```
[dict([(raw_input(), int(raw_input()))]) for i in xrange(1)]
```

Comment: It's messy. In old Python 2 versions it worked "correctly" (i.e. according to spec), then the bug was introduced in 2.5. See [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue11205). It works incorrectly in 3.3, and 3.4, I believe, but was fixed in Python 3.5

Comment: The behavior of list comprehensions is also not what one might expect from the spec, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201932/order-of-operations-in-a-dictionary-comprehension)

Answer (score 0):

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.

Simply it is a bug in Python 2.7.

(In Python3 was the same bug but now it is already fixed.)