# Transform a list to dict with tuple as key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I want to do from list
`['sw0005', 'sw0076', 'Gi1/2', 'sw0005', 'sw0076', 'Gi1/5']`
Dict with tuple, which will looks like
`{('sw0005','sw0076'):'Gi1/2', ('sw0005','sw0076'):'Gi1/5'}`
How's better it can be done in python?

Comment: Your dictionary has two identical keys. You should also show what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `iter` of the list to get the next element, and then the `next` two after that:

```
>>> lst = ['sw0005', 'sw0076', 'Gi1/2', 'sw0006', 'sw0076', 'Gi1/5']        
>>> it = iter(lst)                                                          
>>> {(a, next(it)): next(it) for a in it}                                   
{('sw0005', 'sw0076'): 'Gi1/2', ('sw0006', 'sw0076'): 'Gi1/5'}
```

Note: (a) I changes the list so the two tuples are not the same; (b) this will fail if the number of elements is not divisible by three.

As noted in comments, this only works properly a reasonably new version of Python. Alternatively, you can use a `range` with `step` and the index:

```
>>> {(lst[i], lst[i+1]): lst[i+2] for i in range(0, len(lst), 3)}
{('sw0005', 'sw0076'): 'Gi1/2', ('sw0006', 'sw0076'): 'Gi1/5'}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this solution needs Python3.5 and above - hopefully everyone already is - where the dictionary evaluation order was fixed so that it's keys evaluated before values. _Prior versions of Python_ (3.4, 2.7, etc.) will give the wrong output: `{('sw0005', 'Gi1/2'): 'sw0076', ('sw0006', 'Gi1/5'): 'sw0076'}`; since value expressions are evaluated before key expressions ([was a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28156733/1431750)).

Comment: @aneroid Thanks for pointing out, added alternative.

Comment: @aneroid Makes you wonder if it _should_ be a bug, though. True, expressions should be evaluated left-to-right, but is `key: value` an expression or rather an assignment? In the assignment `d[next(it)] = next(it)`, the RHS, i.e. the value would indeed be evaluated first. (But left-to-right for `key: value` _is_ kind of more intuitive.)

Comment: Well, in the context of a dict comprehension, it is an expression; or rather, they are each expressions. Barring the LHS of an assignment, it's supposed to be left to right. Well, actually, left to right and innermost to outermost in each part of the statement; and RHS before LHS for `=`s. So if `lst = range(0, 10); it = iter(lst)` then these two give different dicts: `{next(it): next(it) for _ in range(0, 5)}` vs `for _ in range(0, 5): d[next(it)] = next(it)`. Which might seem inconsistent but wrt a single expression, I think is the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I made the iterable more readable

```
 list1=['sw0005', 'sw0076', 'Gi1/2', 'sw0005', 'sw0076', 'Gi1/5']

 queryable=iter(list1)

 mylist=[]
 for i in range(int(len(list1)/3)):
     mylist.append({(next(queryable),next(queryable)):next(queryable)})

 print(mylist)
```